# Is there a word for tasks specified in a regimen?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

For example, here is a diet regimen :

> Breakfast: eat cereals, milk, banana.
>
> Lunch : eat Rice, curry and vegetables.
>
> Evening : eat a Sandwich.

or a day long schedule :

> 6: 00 - 7: 00 - Work out
>
> 8:00 - Return library books.
>
> 8:30 - 10: 00 - work on assignment
>
> ...

Is there a generic term for the above listed tasks in the context of a regimen or a schedule.

Comment: @TimLymington. I meant to convey : eat cereals, bananas etc.

Comment: Then edit your question to ask what you really meant (you might also consider [English Language Learners.SE](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).)  But I repeat: what is specified in a diet regimen is a food, and not the task 'eat this food'.

Comment: [Items](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/item)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Articles" is a generic term which means components of something. "Component" is another. You use the word "tasks" above which is also somewhat acceptable though usually would refer to actions rather than objects.